# Classification and regression on same deep learning models?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow

Suppose I have a dataset of photos of people's faces. One face per image. What does the output vector for a single sample look like, and how do I train the network if I want it to:

- predict the age (in days) of the person in the image
- classify the person's gender
- classify country of origin (say, out of only 7 possible options)
- predict (x,y) coordinates of person's nose within the picture (where each coordinate is a value between 0-1, indicating percentage of the distance from top left corner of the input image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a strange question.  "What does the output vector for a single sample look like?",  well, you write the model, so you decide how you chooses to code "the output", which I take to mean $Y$, the response variable that you want to predict. So for your examples:

1. predict the age (in days) of the person in the image.   Output is one number, the age (what else?). But see [Convolutional Neural Network Scale Sensitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327592/convolutional-neural-network-scale-sensitivity)
2. classify the person's gender: Most people still think that gender is binary, so 0/1 coding should do. If in Canada, maybe more complicated ...
3. classify country of origin (say, out of only 7 possible options):  This is a categorical response, so you could use a dummy encoding.
4. predict (x,y) coordinates of person's nose within the picture (where each coordinate is a value between 0-1, indicating percentage of the distance from top left corner of the input image):  Just encode $(x,y)$ in the obvious way, as a pair

If I have misunderstood the question, just explain better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have done more research and practiced in this since asking the question, and your answer is the same conclusion I have arrived at.